# How to cause "OnFailure" for systemd service? If "stop/restart/reload" aren't defined for it

Tags: systemd

I have a systemd script:

```
  [Unit]
  After=syslog.target
  Requires=mysql.service
  OnFailure=-/bin/bash -lc 'source /home/ubuntu/.profile && ./script/my_script_for_failure.sh'

  [Service]
  WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/my_app
  ExecStart=/bin/bash -lc 'source /home/ubuntu/.profile && ./script/my_main_script.sh'
  Restart=always
  RestartSec=10
  StandardOutput=syslog
  StandardError=syslog
  SyslogIdentifier=my_service123
  User=ubuntu
  Group=ubuntu

  [Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The "status" of it shows me this, obfuscated:

```
    $ sudo systemctl status my_systemd.service 
    ● my_systemd.service
       Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/my_systemd.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
       Active: active (running) since 
     Main PID: 23660 (bash)
        Tasks: 5
       Memory: 185.4M
          CPU: 6.752s
       CGroup: /system.slice/my_systemd.service
               ├─23660 /bin/bash -lc source /home/ubuntu/.profile && ./script/my_main_script.sh
               ├─23662 /bin/bash ./script/my_main_script.sh
               └─23663 /home/ubuntu/.gem/ruby/2.3.4/bin/rake jobs:work
```

**My question**:

how can I test or cause "OnFailure"? Is the only way kill all 3 processes by "kill -9 "?

If yes which out of 3 should I kill?

Or one them?

I've tried killing "23663" but "my_script_for_failure" wasn't triggered.

`sudo systemctl status my_systemd.service` won't work because there's no "ExecStop" because "rake jobs:work" don't have the standard way of terminating itself.

Answer (score 2):

OnFailure= is triggered when the state "failed" is reached for the unit, and when no more restart attempts for the service remain (i.e. either Restart= is disabled, or rate-limit has been hit, or understand it as: the next sub state is not going to be auto-restart).

systemd supervises the main PID of the service, and associates state changes to it. So, if it dies uncleanly (exits on its own with an exit code not meant to be interpreted as success) or is killed, the failed state will be reached.

So, killing PID 23660 should trigger the unit registered in OnFailure= AFTER all restart attempts are over (due to rate-limit). Until then, the unit will not be triggered. It could be that you never hit the default StartLimitIntervalSec= and StartLimitBurst= values, and unit keeps restarting on failure, and never stops doing that: in which case, you should tweak them to a suitable value.

Comment: This approach did not work for me. Killing the main process did not invoke OnFailure service at all. However adding non zero exit code to the "to-be-failed" script did actually trigger the OnFailure service